# Drawing on buttons issue

Tags: python, kivy

I have this kivy code for a paint app.

```
<PaintApp>:
    name: "PaintApp"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        CanvasWidget:
            size_hint_y:.9
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(1,None)
            size_hint_y:.1
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: 'Delete'
                font_size: 20
              # on_release: root.clear_canvas()
                background_normal: 'red_button_normal.png'
                background_down: 'red_button_down.png'
                border: (2, 2, 2, 2)
                right: root.right
                top: root.top
                width: 80
                height: 40
            Button:
                text: 'Back'
                font_size: 20
              # on_release: app.root.current= 'ActivitySelectScreen'
                background_normal: 'red_button_normal.png'
                background_down: 'red_button_down.png'
                border: (2, 2, 2, 2)
                right: root.right -80
                top: root.top
                width: 80
                height: 40

            LineWidthButton:
                text: 'Thin'

            LineWidthButton:
                text: 'Normal'
                state: 'down'

            LineWidthButton:
                text: 'Thick'


            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#2980b9')
                state: 'down'

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#16a085')

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#27ae60')

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#f39c12')

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#d35400')

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#c0392b')

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#8e44ad')

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#bdc3c7')

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#7f8c8d')

            ColorButton:
                background_color: C('#2c3e50')
```

Python code:

```
class CanvasWidget(Widget):
    line_width = 2
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if Widget.on_touch_down(self, touch):
            return

        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud['current_line'] = Line(
                points=(touch.x, touch.y),
                width=self.line_width)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if 'current_line' in touch.ud:
            touch.ud['current_line'].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def set_color(self, new_color):
        self.last_color = new_color
        self.canvas.add(Color(*new_color))

    def set_line_width(self, line_width='Normal'):
        self.line_width = {'Thin': 1, 'Normal': 2, 'Thick': 4}[line_width]

    def clear_canvas(self):
        saved = self.children[:]
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.canvas.clear()
        for widget in saved:
            self.add_widget(widget)
```

The output app looks like this:

It somehow draws behind the buttons also. I can't understand why. when I add two buttons in box layout. It doesn't add one on the top of other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: The code is not complete, `LineWidthButton`, `ColorButton` are not defined in python code, not even in kv file, they are only *used*. There are missing imports for various things. Don't do that when you ask... Also, that behavior is not an issue.

Besides that I couldn't run it, I can tell from your describing, that your `CanvasWidget` surely uses whole canvas and not only widget's size/space, ie the drawing will show on the whole screen. The "fix" for this is `StencilView`. You can clearly see in [this demo](https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__canvas__stencil_canvas__py.html) that drawings stay inside a bounding box.

And the buttons, well it's a `BoxLayout` and right at the top of the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html) page for `BoxLayout` you have a gif showing how the layout behaves:

[image]

If you want to place `Button` on another Button, there are other layouts which behave that way. `FloatLayout` for example:

[image]